# Is it fine to show another dialog when your current state is already on a dialog screen?

Tags: modal-windows

Please see example video link. I'm already on a dialog screen then when I deleted the task it shows again another dialog. Is this a good UX? any thought?

[example video showing the dialog](http://screencast.com/t/ZNQsqPOg)

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem by not requiring confirmation to delete. Instead perform the requested action and provide the option to undo, which does not require a modal.

User should only be presented with a confirmation to delete if the item being deleted will be impossible or very difficult to recreate or if it cannot be retrieved from trash.

See http://goodui.org/#8 and http://alistapart.com/article/neveruseawarning

More discussion at [Deletion: Confirm or Undo? Which is the better option and why?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/71960/deletion-confirm-or-undo-which-is-the-better-option-and-why)

Comment: Hi Eric thanks for your feedback. The actual web app is more likely a due diligence task management where buyer archive task. The task involves dealing with USD million project deals using our task management. So most likely we would like to show first the dialog confirmation for archiving task so that when the user accidentally hits the archive button we will just show the archive dialog to confirm. What do you think?

Comment: Is it deleted or archived? Archiving implies that it is retrievable in some way, delete does not. If it is really archiving, it is not a destructive act. It is just moving the task from one state to another, and it can be restored. So you would not need to make the user confirm it if they can go into the archive and retrieve it. This is a case where 90% of users who click "delete" want to delete and it's inconvenient to make the 90% perform a task to protect the 10% from an action that can be easily undone.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is OK to show simple confirm, input, info, alert modal dialog's on top of a complex workflow dialog's like create, edit, search, etc.

And it is not a good idea to show any other dialog on top of elementary dialog's.
And overall it is good to restrict overall dialog/overlay count to 3 or less.

Above that it is difficult for majority of the users to get(comprehend) the nested context of actions and objects on which they are acting.

Comment: Where did you get this number 3 from?