# Is it okay to show action sheet after action sheet in iOS delete flow?

Tags: ios, actions

Delete action is a pretty serious decision for a user, so the best practice is to show some kind of "Are you sure" flow.

But should I do in iOS when the first 'Delete' is in action sheet?
Is it okay to show 'are you sure' + explanation in another action sheet?

What's the best practice here?

Any good examples?

Thanks

Comment: "Are you sure"...or better yet, undelete.

Answer (score 2):

Short: **Yes, confirm the deletion**, but don't use an Action Sheet as a confirmation dialog, you should use an [Alert](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/alerts/) for that:

> Alerts [...] should only be used in important situations like confirming purchases and destructive actions (**such as deletions**) [...]

In their HMI [guidelines on modality](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/modality/) Apple states to minimize modality, but use it for critical actions.

---

Another option is to replace confirmation with the ability to **undo**:
[HMI guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/undo-and-redo/)
[Deletion: Confirm or Undo? Which is the better option and why?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/71960/67657)

---

Might also be interesting for you, for [Action Sheets](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/action-sheets/) they recommend:

> Use red for buttons that perform destructive or dangerous actions, and display these buttons at the top of an action sheet.