# Is having a delete confirmation built into the button itself an appropriate UX?

Tags: mobile, buttons, confirmation

This is for desktop and mobile, basically when you click the button once it changes to "Confirm" with a cancel button next to it. I got some feedback that it's not clear you have to press the button again so maybe I need to make it more clear there is a secondary action here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confirmation of user input: inline button or popup/modal?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/118177/confirmation-of-user-input-inline-button-or-popup-modal)

Answer (score 2):

This is a little odd:

- Having a button proclaim itself to be a button is not necessary. So if anything it'd be "Delete" and "Confirm delete".
- Having a button change itself instead of summoning some type of pop-up-feeling dialog for the confirmation is unusual. It's a bit more ergonomic, sure, but there do exist people who double-click everything because they haven't learned yet that in the context of the web, you don't need to double-click anything. By keeping the confirm step at the same position, a double-click may be interpreted as a very fast click onto the confirm button, you may be depriving a class of users of the confirmation step who have the highest need for it.

Comment: Nice answer. I'd add this to support your second point: this is the main issue for Google's CLS algorithm and UX check. While I don't completely agree with Google's implementation or even definition of CLS (let alone User Experience), it serves as a subjective measure for many people.

Answer (score 0):

It's really confusing that the button changes itself into confirmation. What I suggest is to enable a "cancel deletion" button instead. What I mean is to do this:

1. The delete button is working just fine.
2. Once the user clicks on the delete button, the button would be changed to somethings like this: "XXX deleted. **Cancel deletion**" and you would give some time like 5 seconds for the user to click cancel deletion in case they deleted mistakenly in the first place.

Comment: While a good idea in theory, I think in practice it implies a huge cognitive load. You're actually forcing the user to decide whether their actions are right or wrong within five seconds, and with a required interaction that takes approximately one second. I think a popup dialog with no time limit would be better.

Comment: I agree with you. I was thinking exactly like you before I used some applications that have exactly the same approach as I mentioned. But after that I saw it's actually a very practical way and it also removes the need for the second tap by the user. You can see an example here:
https://www.linkedin.com/posts/sepas-haghighi_userinterface-userexperience-productdesign-activity-7147652424709705728-ltBQ?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop