# Should I show a confirmation pop-up when removing an item from the shopping cart?

Tags: popup, shopping-cart

I came across an article that advised to show a pop-up asking the user if the click to remove an item was intentional, instead of removing it immediately.

But at the same time it's not a practice I encounter often, which means it's not a must-have.

How is it?

I get the idea of making the user confirm such an important action, but at the same time I don't feel like it's a totally bad thing if it's not there in the shopping cart case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> such an important action

Why do you think removing an item from the shopping cart is such a big deal?

I usually remove and add several items before making my order, if i would have to confirm every removing action i would get pretty frustrated.

Instead of making the user confirm you can offer him a way back.
For example amazon does it this way:

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit about this image? I don't know what you mean by it ;) The amount of items?

Comment: Sorry didn't saw that i had it set to german.
First image shows my shopping cart containing 1 item, if i hit "Löschen" which is german for "remove", the items gets removed immediately but amazon offers me a way to undo by placing the link of the product to the "Item has been removed from shopping cart"-message.

Comment: any thoughts/research on if it's better to leave that message indefinitely, fade it away after a while or display an "X" for the user to close it if they want? Personally I'm leaning toward an "X" option.

Comment: It should stay visible as long as the user is on that page, as soon as he leaves because he wants to add another product for example then message should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the question below, it has the answers you are looking for..
In short it is, use Undo instead of confirm, the UX is much better!

**[Deletion: Confirm or Undo? Which is the better option and why?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/71960/deletion-confirm-or-undo-which-is-the-better-option-and-why)**